# How to connect to a server in Windows Command Line (or Powershell) without netcat

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, remote-access, netcat

What is the command in ***Cmd or Powershell*** in Windows to create a connect to server and port? In Linux it's `nc [host] [port]` but in Windows there's no netcat to do this task.

Comment: [Are there netcat-like tools for Windows which are not quarantined as malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/14501/are-there-netcat-like-tools-for-windows-which-are-not-quarantined-as-malware/14508) or maybe [Alternative for "nc -z localhost 3300" for windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058144/alternative-for-nc-z-localhost-3300-for-windows-netcat)

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically want to use:

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername HOSTNAME
```

Beware that there are some requirements to do this.
Running `winrm qc` on the host usually solves the most problems.

See full info on [Enter-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.2).